# Excel Data Validation (List) with IF Contains text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a data validation list where the drop down only contains text like "US" or "EU" to isolate the PO numbers.  The table column I am pulling from can have things like "US12345" or "EU76543" or "ID10987".  I need the list to only show the items that have that US in them.

I tried:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(Table[PO_Number])="US*",INDIRECT(Table[PO_Number]),"")
```

This gives a Value Error.

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how?

Comment: `="US*"` equals with a wildcard will never work.  Can you use `Left(Table[PO_Number],2` ?  `(Left(Table[PO_Number],2))="US"`

Comment: Just tried the above and it also doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data in `Table[PO_Number]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the desired filtered list somewhere within the workbook, as dynamic lists cannot be entered directly within Data Validation.

For example, assuming you have Office 365, this formula in cell `D1`:

`=FILTER(Table[PO_Number],LEFT(Table[PO_Number],2)="US")`

will spill all matching entries.

(Amend the condition - here checking if the initial two letters of the PO Number are "US" - as required.)

For the Data Validation, you can then use the *List* option and set the *Source* to:

`=$D$1#`

Include the sheet name in the above expression if the cells being validated are not in the same sheet as the `FILTER` formula.

Comment: I get "That function isn't valid" for the =FIlter code

Comment: Please confirm your version of Excel